# reading from array but unable to find a match

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array `$result` which looks like this:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(32) "24:no peer certificate available"
}
```

I am trying to use the following to find a match in the array but not working:

```
if (in_array("no peer certificate available", $result)) {
    echo "no peer available";
    } else { echo "peer is available"; }
}
```

Comment: yes, its correct to actually not work, it doesn't match the string entirely

Comment: oh i was missing "24:" -- sorry about that.. i added "24:" to the search and it works now

Comment: yeah, now that should work, it doesn't work when you trying to search just a part of the string, but if its an exact one, it will work

Comment: @Ghost, yep, i overlooked it. thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`in_array` will only work if the `needle` string you're trying to search has an **exact** match inside the `haystack` (the array).

```
24:no peer certificate available
if (in_array("no peer certificate available", $result)) {
```

As an alternative, if you're trying to search just a part of that needle and check those elements, you could use `strpos`:

```
$result = array(
    '24:no peer certificate available'
);

$found = false;
foreach($result as $value) {
    if(strpos($value, 'no peer certificate available') !== false) {
        $found = true;
        break;
    }
}

echo ($found) ? 'peer is available' : 'no peer available';
```

Answer (score 1):

got trigger happy, my string was missing parts of what i was looking for.. added `24:` to my search and the code worked.

@Ghost also confirmed cannot search for part of a string, should be the full string.